# Background HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, background

I'm a beginner in the field, learning HTML and CSS. I'm trying to create a clone of a free Figma portfolio, but I have no idea how to achieve that purple and black background. Can you help me? Thanks, everyone.

https://www.figma.com/file/vz7x4jN5Yra6KZIJT2PWyf/Simple-Portfolio-(Community)?node-id=14%3A280&mode=dev

I tried to use the background: linear-gradient, searched on Google, and nothing worked. I know it might seem easy for some, but for beginners, it's quite confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy you just have to create a purple circle, position it and apply `blur` to it.

```css
body {
    background-color: #121212;
}

.purple-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    left: -2%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(209, 21, 209);
    filter: blur(100px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="purple-circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```